# Consequences of non-vanishing theorems of automorphic $L$-functions

Tags: number-theory

Dirichlet's theorem on the arithmetic progression is proved by studying the Dirichlet $L$-function 
$$
L(s, \chi) = \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\chi(n)}{n^{s}}
$$
for a given Dirichlet character $\chi:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{C}$. The main part of the proof is to show $L(1, \chi)\neq 0$ for a nontrivial (primitive) character $\chi$. Also, it is known that non-vanishing of the Riemann zeta function on $\Re(s) = 1$ is equivalent to the prime number theorem, and I believe that the same is true for Dirichlet $L$-functions and the prime number theorem for the primes of the form $ak + b$, $(a, b) = 1$.

I tried to search some analogous results for general automorphic forms or representations, and it seems that there are some results for $s = 1$. For example,  [this](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/ShalikaBday2002.pdf) article written by Sarnak introduces some results, and [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01390166) paper by Jacquet-Shalika, which proves non-vanishing results on $\Re(s) = 1$ for automorphic $L$-functions associated to cuspidal automorphic representations.

I want to know if there's any interesting consequences of these non-vanishing results for $\mathrm{GL}_{n}$, analogous to Dirichlet's theorem or prime number theorem. 
I guess that if we have a holomorphic cusp form $f:\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{C}$ of weight $k$ (we may assume that it is a newform), then we can attach $L$-function $L(s, f)$, which is essentially automorphic $L$-function $L(s, \pi_{f})$ for some $\pi_{f}$. Can we prove some interesting results about the Fourier coefficients $a_{p}$ of $f(z)$ by using the non-vanishing theorems? For example, if $f(z) = \Delta(z)$, the discriminant function, then what information can we get about $\tau(p)$ from the non-vanishing theorem on $\mathrm{GL}_{2}$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Sato-Tate conjecture uses the non-vanishing of $L(s,\mathrm{Sym}^n(\pi))$ along the (suitably normalized) $s = 1$ line, which is deduce from the potential automorphy of $\mathrm{Sym}^n(\pi)$ together with these non-vanishing results.

Comment: @user670344 Thanks! Maybe this is a silly question, but can we formulate Sato-Tate conjecture for $\mathrm{GL}_{1}$ so that it is already known theorem related to the distribution of primes (like Dirichlet's theorem or prime number theorem)?

Comment: Yes, for $\mathrm{GL}_1/\mathbf{Q}$, one has a finite Dirichlet character $\chi$ of order $n$, and "Sato--Tate" is the predicted distribution of Frobenius elements, which is Dirichlet's Theorem, and via these standard mechanisms is equivalent to the non-vanishing of $L(\chi^k,1)$ for $k$ not divisible by $n$. For $\mathrm{GL}_1/F$, there are other non-algebraic Hecke characters, and so one has not only Chebotarev for abelian extensions but also other distribution results (like equidistribution of angles of Gaussian primes). These were proved by Hecke.

Comment: @user670344 Thank you very much!

Comment: For $L(s,\tau)= \sum_n \tau(n)n^{-11/2} n^{-s}$ (with $\tau$ the coefficients of $\Delta$) having a functional equation $s \to 1-s$ and $O(n^\epsilon)$ coefficients the PNT is $\sum_{p^k \le x} \frac{\tau(p^k)p^{-k 11/2}}{k} = o(\frac{x}{\ln^r x}), \forall r$, the GRH is $O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$. (Because the sign of the coefficients are erratic) the analytic continuation and non-vanishing isn't sufficient, you need the analytic continuation for a few twists, plus some growth estimates on vertical strips.